# Confusion about MX records

Tags: email, dns, linode, mx-record

I'm very confused by the fundamentals of DNS records (in this case MX records).   Right now I have registered a domain name (let's call it example.com).  This domain is configured to my linode's IP via their nameservers.

The default MX record that is in the Domain Manager is 'mail.example.com'. Fair enough.

I followed this tutorial about setting up a exim server.

[Exim Tutorial in Linode Library](http://library.linode.com/email/exim/send-only-mta-ubuntu-10.04-lucid)

and I'm kind of confused.  My default hostname on the machine is 'antares' and thus the FQDN is 'antares.example.com'.  In this tutorial I don't see how this 'mail.example.com' is coming into play?  Where do I specify this?  Or should I point the mail MX record to antares.example.com?

I'm very new to DNS records and even more new to mail records.  Any hints to clarify my misunderstanding would be invaluable.

Comment: maybe posting the question to serverfaults would yield better answers.

Comment: You should point your MX record to the host that's serving SMTP. Which sounds like "antares".  As simple as that :)  And remember: antares.example.com, www.example.com and mail.example.com might all conceivably point to the *same host*.  Why not ;)?

Comment: And was I downvoted because I had no idea that such a site existed?

Comment: So you have a Linux VPS with Linode, are you using named/BIND as your DNS server? If so I can show a complete Zone file as an example.

Comment: @Chimera I'm just using the standard Linode nameservers that are provided.  ns1.linode.com, ns2.linode.com, etc.  I think I'm starting to understand as I see now that exim automatically adds multiple domains as possible recipients (there were even a default of mail.pdgeon.com and antares)

Comment: You are running a Linux Server on a VPS correct? Are you running your own DNS server or is Linode?

Comment: Here's another video you can watch, that might be more helpful. [MX Video](http://www.unlocktheinbox.com/tv/mx-records/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the DNS server for your domain will by default serve up the www or .domain.com entry to web browsers etc but it actually hosts a bunch of name pointers for other services, one of which is mail exchange.

Services which need your mx record value know how to look it up from your DNS server, so in this case they will find mail.domain.com when you supply the domain.com part.

If you need to set up a mail server you will need to change the mx record in your domain manager to point to your machine ip, this can be different from your default www host name/ip on the same domain as every service can be served by a different host (any ip).